# How to run PL/SQL within UltraEdit?

Tags: sqlplus, ultraedit

How can I run [PL/SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL) or SQL from within UltraEdit?

Current I am able to compile the current file like this:

```
sqlplus database/database@pass @%F
```

The above compiles, but what is the command to run?

I do not see a show option here:

[image]

Comment: How do you run pl/sql from command line? The same command can be used in a user tool in UltraEdit where only the file name is replaced by the placeholder __%f__. (Lower case %f means long file name, upper case %F is for 8.3 short file name.)

Comment: If your script interacts with user via keyboard/console window, check the option _Show DOS box_ on __Output__ tab of the user tool configuration. Then you can enter something on prompt. _Capture output_ should not be checked in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlplus apps/apps@dev @%F
```

The above runs the contents of the file. The file should be saved as .sql.